# How do I click on the listview item and get the phone number?

Tags: android, listview

Can't get the information of the list item after I press on the list item

I've looked at many overflow questions so far, and I don't know if I have my listview set up right, but I don't want to mess up how I was able to get the contacts

```
public class ViewContacts extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lv;
    private Cursor cursor1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_contacts);

        cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);
        String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};

        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
        final SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor1, from, to);

        ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder option = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewContacts.this);

                option.setMessage(the phone number);
                option.show();
                }
        });

    }
}
```

press on list item, then have a pop up that displays the phone number

Comment: Use the 'int position' for accessing your string array which has the phones.

aka option.setMessage(from[position]);

Comment: it just displays 'data1'

Comment: and what does the listview says?

Comment: it says: adasd asdasd and then the phone number (273) 273-27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the phone number of the contact item that you tapped on, you need to use `position` to move your cursor to the corresponding *row*, then get the item from the desired column.

Simplified example below that you put inside your `onItemClick`:

```
cursor1.moveToPosition(position);
String phoneNumber = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```

You can replace `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` with any valid column name.

Comment: just get 'data1' with this method.

Comment: something is off with the device you're on... I copied your code and this works for me.

Comment: oh my god i feel like such and idiot, i forgot to change my option.setMessage to phoneNumber... you're solution worked! thank you so much